# iOS/Swift: InAppPurchase invalidProductIdentifiers

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, appstore-sandbox

I have created a single IAP product in iTunes Connect.

Its status is: **Ready to Submit**

On the app Delegate I am using the following code to retrieve the product information:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
     ...
     requestProductData()
     return true
}

func requestProductData() {
     if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
          let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(["xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx"]))
          request.delegate = self
          request.start()
     }
}

func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
     var products = response.products
     print("products:",products.count)
     for product in response.invalidProductIdentifiers {
          print("Product not found: \(product)")
     }
}
```

And I always get: "Product not found: xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx"

I verified the product ID has been written correctly.

I am using a physical device, not a simulator.

The AppleID logged in the physical device has properly been added to the tester sandbox list.

My app has been submitted so far only to TestFlight (without in-app-purchase), and to the the Appstore yet.

**UPDATE:**

my Paid Applications Contract status says: *processing*

might this be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's not possible to test without a valid Paid Applications Contract with Apple -- you need to provide your contact info, bank info, and tax info.

Answer (score 0):

Did your issue get resolved? I've been told by Apple Developer's that there is a global (worldwide) issue related to Agree…Tax…Banking which is also preventing IAPs from working. It's been plaguing them since about Nov 24. As of Dec 2 (2015), still not fixed.

Comment: Yes, it seems there was a global issue, which has today been resolved, at least for me.
If you are still experiencing the issue, I suggest you to contact them to solve your case manually.

Comment: Hi @DanieleB, yes, they resolved my issue same day yours was resolved - Dec 3. It was a relief to have it working again; an Apple rep called me to notify me it had been resolved - I thought that was great customer service on their part.

Comment: Apple developers customer service is absolutely great, no doubt!